# URLSession Type Mismatch Error

Tags: json, swift, jsondecoder

I'm getting an Type Mismatch error when trying to parse json with Swift jSon Decoder.

I just can't find a way to parse it normally.

The Error:

```
typeMismatch(Swift.String, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath:
[CodingKeys(stringValue: "data", intValue: nil), 
CodingKeys(stringValue: "itemArr", intValue: nil), 
CodingKeys(stringValue: "price", intValue: nil)], debugDescription:
"Expected to decode String but found a number instead.",
underlyingError:
nil))
```

The Decoder Code:

```
 func getDealDetails(id : String ,completion : @escaping ()->())
{
    let jsonUrl = "https://androidtest.inmanage.com/api/1.0/android/getDeal_\(id).txt"
    guard let url = URL(string: jsonUrl) else { return }

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in

        guard let data = data else { return }

        do
        {
            let deal = try JSONDecoder().decode(ResultDetails.self, from: data)
            AppManager.shared.dealToShow = deal.data.itemArr

        }catch
        {
            print("There's an error: \(error)")
        }

        completion()

        }.resume()



}
}
```

And The Classes:

First:

```
class ResultDetails : Decodable
{
  let data : DataDetails

init(data : DataDetails) {
    self.data = data
}


}
```

Second:

```
class DataDetails : Decodable
{
 let itemArr: ItemArr

init(itemArr: ItemArr) {
    self.itemArr = itemArr
}
}
```

And Third:

```
class ItemArr : Decodable
{
let id, title, price, description: String
let image: String
let optionsToShow: Int
let gps: Gps
let website, phone: String

  init(id: String, title: String, price: String, description: String,   image: String, optionsToShow: Int, gps: Gps, website: String, phone: String) {
    self.id = id
    self.title = title
    self.price = price
    self.description = description
    self.image = image
    self.optionsToShow = optionsToShow
    self.gps = gps
    self.website = website
    self.phone = phone
}
```

I think I tried everything for the last 6 hours to fix it, please help!

EDIT:

I put a wrong third class. now it's the right one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you have an error

`let price: Int`  should be `let price: String` because it string in Json `"price": "896"`  -- > String

Example for Int  `"optionsToShow":1` --> this is Int

**Here is complete code you can use**

```
import Foundation
struct ResultDetails: Codable {
    let data: DataDetails
}

struct DataDetails: Codable {
    let itemArr: ItemArr
}

struct ItemArr: Codable {
    let id, title, price, description: String
    let image: String
    let optionsToShow: Int
    let gps: Gps
    let website, phone: String
}

struct Gps: Codable {
    let lat, lon: String
}
// MARK: Convenience initializers

extension ResultDetails {
    init(data: Data) throws {
        self = try JSONDecoder().decode(ResultDetails.self, from: data)
    }

    init(_ json: String, using encoding: String.Encoding = .utf8) throws {
        guard let data = json.data(using: encoding) else {
            throw NSError(domain: "JSONDecoding", code: 0, userInfo: nil)
        }
        try self.init(data: data)
    }


    func jsonData() throws -> Data {
        return try JSONEncoder().encode(self)
    }

    func jsonString(encoding: String.Encoding = .utf8) throws -> String? {
        return String(data: try self.jsonData(), encoding: encoding)
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, Thanks, I accidentally put a wrong code in the third class. now I fix it, can you please take a look again? here the price is String

Comment: yes now it works ok Just don't forget to add `GPS class or struct`

Comment: I used Strucks, Still Same Problem:                TypeMismatch(Swift.String, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "data", intValue: nil), CodingKeys(stringValue: "itemArr", intValue: nil), CodingKeys(stringValue: "price", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected to decode String but found a number instead.", underlyingError: nil))

Comment: just slowly you have all code above check what is difference , above code works good

Comment: Should I put all the structs on the same place that I'm writing the son parsing code or I can make a separate file to each struct? where should I put the ResultDetails Extension?

Comment: thanks friend, I figure it out. the price was int not string

Comment: I found that in one object the price is String and in all of the others it is Int! I have the id of the object that the price is string in it, is there a way to force cast it to string or int or to parse with an " if id == (the id that have price string ) " force price to be int " " or something like that?

Comment: here's one simple way to solve this with Codable directly, by overriding `init(from:):`

Answer (score 2):

The error message is wrong. According to the JSON link and your classes it's supposed to be

> CodingKeys(stringValue: **"price"**, intValue: nil)], debugDescription:
>   **Expected to decode Int but found a string/data instead.**,

However it's going to tell you exactly what's wrong: The value for key `price` is a `String` rather than an `Int`.

You have to read the JSON carefully. The format is very simple. For example **everything** in double quotes is `String`, there is **no** exception.

---

Your data structure is too complicated. Use structs and drop the initializers. By the way there is a typo `ItemsArr` vs. `ItemArr` and there is no key `orderNum`.

The key `image` can be decoded as URL. This is sufficient

```
struct ResultDetails : Decodable {
    let data : DataDetails
}

struct DataDetails : Decodable {
    let itemArr: ItemArr
}

struct ItemArr : Decodable {
    let id, title: String
    let price: String
    let image: URL
    // let orderNum: Int
}
```

Specify the `CodingKeys` only if you want to map the keys. In your case you can even omit the `CodingKeys`, use the`convertFromSnakeCase` strategy instead.

```
decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
```

Comment: Hey, Thanks, I accidentally put a wrong code in the third class. now I fix it, can you please take a look again? here the price is String

Comment: It looks correct. Once again don't use classes. The decoder doesn't call those initializers anyway. And decode `image` and `website` as URL

Comment: I used Strucks, Still Same Problem:                TypeMismatch(Swift.String, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "data", intValue: nil), CodingKeys(stringValue: "itemArr", intValue: nil), CodingKeys(stringValue: "price", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected to decode String but found a number instead.", underlyingError: nil))

Comment: The JSON in the link and my suggested structs do work. Then the real JSON is different. This error message says the value for key `price` is `Int`.

Comment: I double checked it, you were right, the price was accidentally  string.